# JQuery not returning value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using [Valum's AJAX file uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). I am trying to send a parameter with the GET request made by the jQuery plugin. This code used to work a few hours ago. But it isn't now!

Can't see any error in Firebug either.

Help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#newProject").colorbox({width:"38%",inline:true, href:"#project-new"});

    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('projectCsv'),
        action: 'new-project.php',                        
        params: {
            name: $('#projectName').val()
        },
        onSubmit: function(){
            if($('#projectName').val().length < 4)    {
                alert('Project name should be at least 4 characters long.');
                return false;                            
            }                            
        },
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
            var result = responseJSON.success;
            if(result==true)
                location.reload();
            else
                return true;
        }
    });                  
});
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know exactly how this code fails to work.

Comment: Isn't it very frustating? Code looks okay. But doesn't work!

Comment: If you've figured out what's wrong, please answer your own question or just delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it around by editing the fileuploader.js (line 1183). 
Added

`params['name'] = $('#projectName').val();`

and it works well now